# Using `await` within a .map works but seems to skip the parent's `await` functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an rss.xml.js file that runs this script in a project using the astro framework.

```
import rss from "@astrojs/rss";
import { fetchFeed } from "../lib/api";

export async function get(context) {
  const posts = await fetchFeed();

  return rss({
    title: "My Online Store",
    description: "Online For Everyone",
    site: context.site,
    items: posts.map((post) => ({
      title: post.title,
      pubDate: Date.now(),
      description: post.description,
      // customData: post.data.customData,
      // Compute RSS link from post `slug`
      // This example assumes all posts are rendered as `/blog/[slug]` routes
      link: post.url,
    })),
  });
}
```

normally the fetchFeed function has its `await` functionality and it works fine. However in this particular case I had to make the `map` method too as an async. That, to me, seems to be the only difference between my previous site, where this worked and the current one, where it's not working.

```
export const fetchFeed = async function () {
  const allPosts = await import.meta.glob("./../pages/**/*.md");
  // console.log("allPosts", allPosts);
  const posts = Object.values(allPosts).map(async (postData) => {
    const post = await postData();
    // console.log("inside", post.frontmatter);
    return { ...post.frontmatter, url: post.url };
  });

  return posts;
};
```

When I console.log the posts (in the rss.xml.js) I realise that `posts` doesn't exist as the fetchFeed function call is not yet resolved. And it resolves after the rss() function has been called.

I assumed the `await` keyword would delay the return till it was resolved... but that's not what is happening.

Could someone help me and point out what I am doing wrong? I am not very good with Promises and I would appreciate some help.

Regards,

Alim

Comment: use `return Promise.all(posts)` - since `posts` is an array of Promises. Now your function caller can wait for that one promise to resolve to an array of results

Comment: `.map()` produces an array.  When you pass it an `async` callback function, since all `async` functions return a promise, what you get from `.map()` is an array of promises.  You have to use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the promises in the array to resolve and end up with an array of values.

Comment: `await` only affects the execution of the nearest `async` function (in this case the one in the `.map()`). It is an easy fix though, because you just have to put an `await` into the outer `async` function too (first you have to convert an array of Promises into a Promise resolving to an array, that's what `Promise.all()` does).

Comment: Thanks guys ... all your inputs were helpful.. and the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `posts` is an array of Promises. You need to await that.

```
  const posts = await Promise.all(Object.values(allPosts).map(async (postData) => {
    const post = await postData();
    // console.log("inside", post.frontmatter);
    return { ...post.frontmatter, url: post.url };
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `promise.all`

Code will be like this:

```js
export async function get(context) {
  const postsPromises = await fetchFeed();

  const posts = await Promise.all(postsPromises);

  return rss({
    title: "My Online Store",
    description: "Online For Everyone",
    site: context.site,
    items: posts.map((post) => ({
      title: post.title,
      pubDate: Date.now(),
      description: post.description,
      link: post.url,
    })),
  });
}
```